# Intramaps Roam GPS_LOG not honoring Tracking settings

Tags: qgis, gps, intramaps-roam

I have Roam 2.5.2 and enabled the gps_log layer as discussed here: https://roam-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/Features-2.1/#gps-logging-and-tracking

For most part it works well, however it seems to be recording points every second, even though the setting 'GPS Feature Tracking' is set to Every 10 second.
[image]
[image]
After an hour or two we have almost a Gig of point data, which is unusable in that it takes forever to load while panning the map.

Is there another way to set this value?

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'bug' in Roam, as the value is hard coded as a maximum of a one second update rate (higher if you have a slower GPS).

In short the answer is no, you cannot change the value.

You could change the update rate of your GPS but depending of your device that could be difficult.

I have just added an update to the project to have this fixed in the next release https://github.com/roam-qgis/Roam/pull/447. If its really important to have the functionality now, you could build Roam from source with the changes in the  Pull Request if you want the functionality now.

Answer (score -1):

Best to post this in the GitHub project. The developers are very active on that forum, although the port to QGIS3 may slow things a little.

https://github.com/roam-qgis/Roam/issues

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you saying that this is likely to be a bug and therefore the business of the product's developers?